# VBA Run time error 1004: Unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class

Tags: vba, excel

VBA Run time error 1004: Unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class

I've followed Dick Kusleika's advice in this [link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/), but can't get the following array formula to enter into excel via VBA. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Both halves of the formula are easily below 255 characters.

```
Public Sub Configuration()

Dim theFormulaPart1 As String

Dim theFormulaPart2 As String

theFormulaPart1 = "=IF(ISODD(B2),IFERROR(INDEX(Race1Grid,MATCH(C2&I2&""Q3""," & _
                "QualRace1ID&QualDriver&QSession,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Race1Grid" & _
                ",MATCH(C2&I2&""Q2"",QualRace1ID&QualDriver&QSession,0)),INDEX" & _
                "(Race1Grid,MATCH(C2&I2,QualRace1ID&QualDriver,0))))," & _
                "X_X_X())"

theFormulaPart2 = "IFERROR(INDEX(Race2Grid,MATCH(C2&I2&""Q3"",QualRace2ID&" & _
                "QualDriver&QSession,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Race2Grid,MATCH(C2&" & _
                "I2&""Q2"",QualRace2ID&QualDriver&QSession,0)),INDEX(" & _
                    "Race2Grid,MATCH(C2&I2,QualRace2ID&QualDriver,0)))))"

    With Worksheets("Races").Range("V2")
        .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
        .Replace "X_X_X())", theFormulaPart2
    End With

End Sub
```

I have tried splitting the formula onto more lines to make it easier to read.

Comment: You've used `Formula` instead of `FormulaArray`.

Comment: I edited the question already...

Comment: The first part of your formula is still too long.

Comment: The first part of the array formula is 229 characters?

Comment: You need to make sure that it's under 255 in R1C1 format too. Yours isn't - it's about 279.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, it's just the length of the first part of the formula. I suggest you simplify further:

```
Public Sub Configuration()

Dim theFormulaPart1 As String

Dim theFormulaPart2 As String

Dim theFormulaPart3 As String

theFormulaPart1 = "=IF(ISODD(B2),X_X_X1(),X_X_X())"
theFormulaPart3 = "IFERROR(INDEX(Race1Grid,MATCH(C2&I2&""Q3""," & _
                "QualRace1ID&QualDriver&QSession,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Race1Grid" & _
                ",MATCH(C2&I2&""Q2"",QualRace1ID&QualDriver&QSession,0)),INDEX" & _
                "(Race1Grid,MATCH(C2&I2,QualRace1ID&QualDriver,0)))),"
theFormulaPart2 = "IFERROR(INDEX(Race2Grid,MATCH(C2&I2&""Q3"",QualRace2ID&" & _
                "QualDriver&QSession,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Race2Grid,MATCH(C2&" & _
                "I2&""Q2"",QualRace2ID&QualDriver&QSession,0)),INDEX(" & _
                    "Race2Grid,MATCH(C2&I2,QualRace2ID&QualDriver,0)))))"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("V2")
        .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
        .Replace "X_X_X())", theFormulaPart2
        .Replace "X_X_X1()", theFormulaPart3
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, broken down into three it now at least goes in without the 1004 error. Caveat - I'm actually trying to insert this formula into a Table, and after running the macro V2 shows #VALUE! If I click the cell and hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter, it goes in as an array. What gives? .FormulaArray was specified in the Sub!

Comment: Does it appear in the cell initially with {} around it?

Comment: No, but the code that both you and I have used states `.FormulaArray = `so I am a little perplexed...

Comment: Weirdly, the code is no longer making the second substitution for me - but it *is* going in as an array formula (Excel 2010)

Comment: I don't think you can insert an long array formula, using replace, into a table and have the formula successfully copy down in that column. It's not working for me beyond the first cell.

Comment: To elaborate, could it be because the table contains its own form of 'named ranges' - i.e. `=Table1[@GRID]`? (Gleaned from here: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/)

Comment: The solution was to insert the formula outside the Table range, then use `.Range("V2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False` to put it in the table as an array formula.

Comment: One last thing, which perhaps you have some ideas on: This formula and method works fine, but I'm also inserting it into a Table where sometimes B2 is empty. The logic `ISODD()` will throw a #VALUE! in this case. I tried encasing in `IFERROR` but it seems that the technique of splitting the array formula in two in VBA won't allow this, perhaps because the parentheses are no longer balanced in the two parts. Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: Depends what you want to happen. Shouldn't be an issue to adjust the formula so that you can replace the correct number of parentheses.

Comment: Balancing the parentheses can be achieved by replacing `X_X_X())` with `""""),"""")`. Why? Because adding an extra `IFERROR` to the front of the formula introduces an extra opening parenthesis which needs to be balanced by an extra closing one. Including the blank speech marks marks the first part of the array formula valid if the replace was to fail. Thanks for your help Rory.