# Unable to get the formularArray property of the range class

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code, I get this error:

> unable to set the formulararray property of the range class

```
Sub Auto_TTAnalysis_RANREPORT()
'
' Auto_TTAnalysis_RANREPORT Macro
'

'
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("M1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BTS"
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Category"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Outage in ins"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "15 mins"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No Site Outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cell Outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst Cell"",""Site Outage"")))"
    Range("N2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=(100-AVERAGEIFS(C[-3],C[-13],RC[-2]))*24*60/100"
    Range("O2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]>15,""More than 15 mins"",""Within 15  mins"")"
    Range("P2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$8275").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="0.00"
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Range("K1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("HUAWEI").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Size = 9
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Columns("I:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("N1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Category"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Outages in min"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "15 mins"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No site outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cell outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst cell"",""Site outage"")))"
    Range("N2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=(100-AVERAGEIFS(C[-3],C[-13],RC[-2]))*24*60/100"
    Range("O2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]>15,""More than 15 mins"",""Within 15 mins"")"
    Range("P2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Sheets("ZTE").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("K1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("N1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Category"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OUTAGES IN MINS"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "15MINS"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No site outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cell outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst cell"",""Site Outage"")))"
    Range("N2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=(100-AVERAGEIFS(C[-3],C[-13],RC[-2]))*24*60/100"
    Range("O2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]>15,""More than 15 mins,""""Within15mins"")"
    Range("P2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]>15,""More than 15 mins"",""Within 15 mins"")"
    Range("P2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("M1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$1586").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="0.00"
    Range("A168").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Range("K1581").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("HUAWEI").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$22388").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="0"
    Range("A485").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Range("K1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("ERICSON").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: first step would be to invest a little time in cleaning up all of those .Select statements. That will greatly help simplify your code and make it easier to debug.

Comment: Not to mention you clearly should review your own post, it's nearly impossible to read atm.

Comment: Alright, at least I tryed, but I could not edit your question because of the enormous amount of code. Can you reduce it to something more relevant to the problem? You can start with a line that throws an error.

Comment: @AntiDrondert - a brave stab. I think we can only conclude that the OP is not serious about wanting help.

Comment: This seems to have just been a straight copy/paste of a Recorded macro - you can probably drop all but the last `Application.CutCopyMode=False` and you have several blocks where you are either using `.Select` or `With Selection` in a row that can be pared down less lines for the same result.  But, in general, try to replace `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveCell` wherever possible with proper Range definitions line `Range("B:B").Copy` and `Columns("M:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: Also - when you fill a formula down, you probably want to run `Application.Calculate` before you copy/paste it, to make sure that it has finished recalculating

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your problem, though I might be mistaken, since no way I'm going to debug it.
**This line**

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No Site Outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cell Outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst Cell"",""Site Outage"")))"
```

**will probably throw an error because the number of characters is over 255.**
[Related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40679027/8282232)
[See Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213181/run-time-error-using-formulaarray-property)
A workaround that might work for you is something like this:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100)," & _
            """No Site Outage""," & _
            "IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100)," & _
                """No Cell Outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5," & _
                                        """Worst Cell""," & _
                                        """Site Outage"")))"
```

It calculates array formula comprised of multiple strings, each of those is less than 255 characters.

Comment: I have generally found that to put Array Formulae longer than 255 characters you need to do something like `.FormulaArray = "=Max(1)"` and then follow it up with `.Replace("Max(1)", "PutYourReallyLongFormulaHere")`

Comment: @Chronocidal n1! I'll check this one later!

Comment: Just double checked.  `Replace` still has the 255 character limit, but you can chain it to break it down into chunks < 255 charaters: `.FormulaArray = "=IF(Condition1, Max(1), Max(2))"` then `.Replace "Max(1)", "Value1"` and `.Replace "Max(2)", "If(Condition2, Value2, Max(2))"` before finally `.Replace "Max(2)", "Value3")` etc - you just have to make sure that each stage is 'valid' on its own

Answer (score 1):

(I am expanding my comments on AntiDrondert's answer to a full answer of its own.)

The `.FormulaArray` property only accepts up to 255 characters.  You can get around this with the `.Replace` method, but that also only accepts 255 characters per argument.  (You can repeat it to make the formula in the array as long as you like though)

I am going to update your *first* Array Formula as an example, so that you can make matching changes to the rest yourself.

```
Range("N2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No Site Outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cell Outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst Cell"",""Site Outage"")))"
Range("N2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Now, your formula is only slightly over (still under 300 characters) so in theory we only *need* 1 replace - but I will use 2 so that each of your `IF` blocks is on a separate line.

```
With Range("N2")
    'Each stage in the replace has to be a valid formula.  MAX(1) is short, and unusual, so easy to find/replace
    .FormulaArray = "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No Site Outage"",MAX(1))"
    .Replace "MAX(1)", "IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cell Outage"",Max(1))"
    .Replace "MAX(1)", "IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst Cell"",""Site Outage"")"
End With
With Range(Range("N2"), Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    .FillDown
    .Calculate
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```