# ERROR 1004 when trying to use FormulaArray. Replace trick does not work

Tags: vba, excel

**BACKGROUND:** I got a cool Array Formula and it works perfect in Excel. Now I'm trying to do the same formula, but with VBA. So I typed the Array Formula in a cell and recorded with a macro. The formula works perfect. The macro recorder gets me this:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=INDEX('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,MATCH(MAX(IF(RIGHT('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""["" &R[-1]C&""]"",'[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C2)),IF(RIGHT('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""[""&R[-1]C&""]"",'[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C2),0),1)"
```

If I try to run the code above, I get error 1004. The sub has just that line. Nothing else.

After some researching I got into this:

[VBA Run time error 1004: Unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679027/vba-run-time-error-1004-unable-to-set-the-formulaarray-property-of-the-range-cl)

[Entering Long Array Formulas In VBA](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/)

So I splitted the formula into 2 parts:

```
Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
Dim theFormulaPart2 As String
Dim MiReemplazo As String
MiReemplazo = "cacota"

theFormulaPart1 = "=INDEX('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,MATCH(MAX(IF(RIGHT('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""["" &R[-1]C&""]"",'[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C2))," & MiReemplazo & ",0),1)"
theFormulaPart2 = "IF(RIGHT('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""[""&R[-1]C&""]"",'[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C2)"

With ActiveSheet.Range(“F2”)
        .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
        .Replace MiReemplazo, theFormulaPart2
    End With
```

And I get no errors, but the part `.Replace MiReemplazo, theFormulaPart2` does nothing (I mean, the replace does not happen, but the code executes)

Also, tried with:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F2").FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
        DoEvents
        Cells.Replace What:=MiReemplazo, Replacement:=theFormulaPart2, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But nothing. So I'm kinda out of ideas.

Also, checked the lenght of both formulas strings (173,107). Do I need sorther strings?

**THINGS I'M PRETTY SURE ARE NOT A PROBLEM:**

1. The formula in Excel works if I type it manually. So is not a problem of the Formula itself
2. I'm just working in 1 cell and trying to get 1 value in the cell of other workbook, so is not a problem of memory or resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `cacota` a named range?

Comment: Is 21076 the only worksheet in HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx?

Comment: @ScottCraner Nope, it's not. Is just a word to replace. Nothing in any of the workbooks, ranges or values is `cacota`

Comment: @Jeeped. Nope, there are more worksheets. why? :O

Comment: My method below demands that at least 1 worksheet remain in the external workbook.

Comment: 1.  the formulas need to be something that can be pasted without an error returning.  Change `"cacota"` to `"C16000"` 2. Then follow @Rory's suggestion.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks! I should have thought about that, because indeed, when I paste the first part (string in `TheFormulaPart1`) it is pasted, but throws a `#¡name!` error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd bet your Excel is not set to use R1C1 referencing, so the replace won't work as you're trying to put an R1C1 referenced string into an A1 style formula. Try using:

```
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
With ActiveSheet.Range("F2")
        .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
        .Replace MiReemplazo, theFormulaPart2
    End With
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it tomorrow and let you know. But i did a test on another PC (with no access to the workbooks I need) and checked the formula and looks like it works. I get a `#¡REF!` error, probably because this PC have no access. But checked the text of the formula and it is complete, so I'm pretty sure this will work! :)  Let me test it tomorrow.

Comment: You were right! Just added your code and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I would personally add a little to the above, so as not to annoy users.  At the top `Dim currRefStyle as integer: currRefStyle=Application.ReferenceStyle` then change the last line to `Application.ReferenceStyle=currRefStyle`.  That way, if the user is using R1C1 it won't change their preferences.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little time consuming due to forced recalculation of a moved object but it seems to work well.

Problem: external workbook references are pushing array formula over the character limit.

Solution: a) move the external worksheet to the local workbook b) complete the array formula insertion c) move the local worksheet back to the external workbook and let Excel figure it out.

```
Sub arrayFormulaTooBig()
    Dim ha2ndx As Long, wbha As Workbook, wbf As Workbook
    Dim sel As Range

    Set sel = Selection

    Set wbha = Workbooks("HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx")
    Set wbf = sel.parent.parent

    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationmanual
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'move the external worksheet to local and reduce worksheet name to minimum characters
    With wbha
        If .Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
            .Worksheets.Add after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Name = "to be removed"
        End If
        With .Worksheets("21076")
            ha2ndx = .Index
            .Move after:=wbf.Worksheets(wbf.Worksheets.Count)
        End With
    End With

    'minimize worksheet name
    wbf.Worksheets("21076").Name = ChrW(215)

    'from 282 characters
    'Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=INDEX('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,MATCH(MAX(IF(RIGHT('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""["" &R[-1]C&""]"",'[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C2)),IF(RIGHT('[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""[""&R[-1]C&""]"",'[HOGARES ALBACETE.xlsx]21076'!C2),0),1)"
    'to 137 characters
    sel.FormulaArray = _
        "=INDEX(×!C1,MATCH(MAX(IF(RIGHT(×!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""["" &R[-1]C&""]"",×!C2)),IF(RIGHT(×!C1,LEN(R[-1]C)+2)=""[""&R[-1]C&""]"",×!C2),0),1)"

    With wbf
        With .Worksheets(ChrW(215))
            .Move before:=wbha.Worksheets(ha2ndx)
        End With
    End With

    'restore worksheet name
    wbha.Worksheets(ChrW(215)).Name = "21076"

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbha.Worksheets("to be removed").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort @Jeeped. You always try to help and thanks. I'll try to adapt this to get all the worksheets I need. Copying the worksheets and then using an easier formula would be better I guess. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot copy the worksheets. You need to Move them in order to have Excel's overhead take care of the range reference changes.

Comment: *You need to Move them in order to have Excel's overhead take care of the range reference changes*. True! I'll do it as you say then. Thanks again!