# Excel vba formula string: array formula - how to simulate Ctrl+Shift+Enter press

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with data and some columns which I fill with formulas via vba. The formula I struggle with is an array formula that looks like this:

```
Workbooks(job_file).Worksheets(1).Cells(h + b, 195).Formula = _
            "{=IF(MAX(IF(B2:M2>$FY" & currentRow & ",$B$1:$M$1))=0,0," & _
              "MAX(IF(sheet1!B2:M2>$FY" & currentRow & "," & _
                                "sheet1!$B$1:$M$1)))+1}"
```

It's supposed to be an array formula, so that's why I put `{}` there. However, when run it simply display the formula's text in a cell, without calculating it. I have to manually remove the brackets, and then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` myself.

Is there any way to avoid it? I have a great many rows and I can't ctrlshiftenter each.

I tried running it without brackets, it works, but gives a `#VALUE!` error, which can also be fixed by applying `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: Remove the `{}` and use `.FormulaArray` not `.Formula`

Comment: Don't forget to mention the smaller character limit in your answer @ScottCraner.

Comment: Whenever you are wondering how to simulate any manual task in Excel, use the macro recorder and see what it makes. Then improve it a bit.

Comment: If you record a macro, you would see that the `.FormulaArray` gets formulas in `R1C1` format only. Thus, you have to rewrite your code a bit. But the best case is to record it first.

Comment: @Vityata - good point about FormulaArray accepting both xlR1C1 and xlA1 style formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an array formula with a simulated ctrl+shift+enter (aka CSE), use the [Range.FormulaArray Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formulaarray-property-excel) instead of the [Range.Formula Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formula-property-excel) and let Excel add the 'curly braces'.

```
with Workbooks(job_file).Worksheets(1)
    .Cells(h + b, 195).FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(MAX(IF(B2:M2>$FY" & currentRow & ",$B$1:$M$1))=0,0," & _
            "MAX(IF(sheet1!B2:M2>$FY" & currentRow & ", sheet1!$B$1:$M$1)))+1"
end with
```

I noticed in your formula that you use `B2:M2` and `sheet1!B2:M2`. Shouldn't they **both** be `sheet1!B2:M2`?

There are some considerations.

- Runtime Error: 1004 - Too long. There is a reduced character limit of 255 for FormulaArray but [there are work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196290/error-1004-when-trying-to-use-formulaarray-replace-trick-does-not-work/51197173?s=1|0.0000#51197173).
- Runtime Error: 1004 - Broken String. Remember that all quotes within a quoted string must be doubled up. This is easily one of the most common causes of errors when trying to write a formula into a cell through VBA. Hint: `TEXT(,)` can be used instead of `""` so you don't have to type `""""` for a zero-length string.
- FormulaArray accepts both xlR1C1 and xlA1 style formulas. If you can wrap your head around xlR1C1 style formula syntax, it is generally easier to construct a concatenated formula string in xlR1C1 since you can use digits to represent column numbers instead of trying to convert column ordinals to a column letter. However, do not try to mix-and-match xlA1 and xlR1C1 range references in the same formula; they must all be one style or the other.
- If you are having trouble formulating a string that will be accepted as a formula, put a tick (e.g. `'` ) in front of the first equals sign then run the code and return to the worksheet to see what was put in. Make modifications on the worksheet until you have a working formula then transfer those modifications to the VBA code.

Answer (score 2):

As a note, it looks like this can be done without an array formula, like so:

```
Workbooks(job_file).Worksheets(1).Cells(h + b, 195).Formula = _
        "=IF($FY" & currentRow & ">MAX(B2:M2),0," & _
         "MAX(INDEX((B2:M2>$FY" & currentRow & ")*$B$1:$M$1,)))+1"
```