# Array Formulas in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, error-handling

I am using for the first time an array formula in VBA and when I run the macro I always get the error "application-defined or object-defined error".
Do you have any idea where my mistake is. I cant find it.

I am trying to use a VLOOKUP with multiple criteria. 1st criteria: Match the text in cell C10. 2nd critera: Match the text = "Total Revenue (excl. Financial Result)". When I use the formula without VBA to test it, it works perfectly.

I defined all the variables and they work in other parts of the code.

```
Dim openRecentPath As String
Dim openRecentPath2 As String
Dim PathIfThere As String
Dim FileIfThere As String
Dim Orderlist2017 As String
Dim Orderlist2018 As String
Dim Orderlist2019 As String
Dim PathIfNotThere As String
Dim FileIfNotThere As String
Dim Datadump As String


PathIfThere = Sheets("Open latest file").Range("J5")
PathIfNotThere = Sheets("Open latest file").Range("J6")
FileIfThere = Sheets("Open latest file").Range("L5")
FileIfNotThere = Sheets("Open latest file").Range("L6")
Orderlist2018 = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("K2")
Datadump = Sheets("Filepaths for P25 2017").Range("M2")
```

As per the comment below I edited the code to less than 255 characters but there is still a mistake somewhere? I tested the code now in different ways and figured that it works up until the MATCH function. After that there is somewhere a small mistake? Please help guys!!

```
Range("G10").FormulaArray = "=If(C10="""","""",INDEX('" & PathIfNot & FileIfNot & Datadump & "'!$K:$K, MATCH(1,('" & PathIfNot & FileIfNot & Datadump & "'!$A:$A=C10)*('" & PathIfNot & FileIfNot & Datadump & "'!$H:$H=24),0)))"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: The text in a .FormulaArray is restricted to 255 characters.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, is there a way around it?

Comment: Sure there are a number of ways. [Here's a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196290/error-1004-when-trying-to-use-formulaarray-replace-trick-does-not-work/51197173?s=2|0.0000#51197173). If you post an example of what your formula turns out to be then real suggestions could be offered.

Comment: Hi guys, as I am relatively new to VBA I decided to just reduce the array formula to less than 255 characters. I edited the Code above but there is still somewhere a mistake and I cannot find it. Would be really appreciate if you can help me out here.

Comment: I have been looking at the code all day and cant find the mistake. Please please help me out!!

Comment: @Jeeped I changed the code to be less than 255 characters but still get this 1004 error code. Are you able to spot an error in the code above or do you know how I could get rid of this error?