# Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class (and formula already broken in three parts)

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the error "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class" with an array formula. I didn't know about the 255 characters limitation, so after I found out, I broke the formula in two pieces, but the error happened again, and again with the formula broken in three pieces (which are definetely below 255 characters).

Here's the code **(see update below)**:

```
Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
Dim theFormulaPart2 As String
Dim theFormulaPart3 As String

theFormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(IF([@[Estado 2]]=""Vigente"",IF(OR(RC15=Componentes!R16C2, RC15=Componentes!R17C2), RC17*INDEX(Componentes!R58C5:R110C19," & _
"X_X_X())"

theFormulaPart2 = "MATCH(1, (RC[-17]=Componentes!R58C5:R110C5)*(RC[-13]=Componentes!R58C7:R110C7), 0), MATCH(MONTH(Componentes!R5C12)," & _
"Y_Y_Y())"

theFormulaPart3 = "Componentes!R60C5:R60C19, 0))+VLOOKUP(RC23,Componentes!R58C5:R110C6,2,FALSE)*RC17*IF(OR(RC27=""Mensual"", RC27=""Anual""," & _
"RC27=""Trimestral""), 30, IF(RC7-Componentes!R5C12=0,1,(RC7-Componentes!R5C12))), ""-""),""-""),""rev"")" & _
""

With ActiveCell.Range("AN7")
    .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
    .Replace "X_X_X())", theFormulaPart2
    .Replace "Y_Y_Y())", theFormulaPart3
End With
```

The debugger sends me to ".FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1".

By the way, the formula works fine "outside" VBA, with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and its function is to make an equation using certain constants from a table, given three inputs.

**UPDATE: I made the formula look like a functional one, and I added corrections from this post, but I am still missing something**:

Now the problem is with the Replace part. Going step by step through the macro, when theFormulaPart2 and theFormulaPart3 are to be replaced, Excel detects an invalid formula ("There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? (...)" and do not replace `Parte1` and `Parte2`.

```
Range("AN7").Select
Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
Dim theFormulaPart2 As String
Dim theFormulaPart3 As String
Dim Parte1 As String
Dim Parte2 As String
Parte1 = "1"
Parte2 = "2"

theFormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(IF([@[Estado 2]]=""Vigente"",IF(OR(RC15=Componentes!R16C2,RC15=Componentes!R17C2),RC17*(" & Parte1 & ")+VLOOKUP(RC23,Componentes!R58C5:R110C6,2,FALSE)*RC17*(" & Parte2 & "),""-""),""-""),""rev"")"

theFormulaPart2 = "INDEX(Componentes!R58C5:R110C19,MATCH(1,(RC[-17]=Componentes!R58C5:R110C5)*(RC[-13]=Componentes!R58C7:R110C7),0)," & _
"MATCH(MONTH(Componentes!R5C12),Componentes!R60C5:R60C19,0))"

theFormulaPart3 = "IF(OR(RC27=""Mensual"", RC27=""Anual"",RC27=""Trimestral""), 30, IF(RC7-Componentes!R5C12=0,1,(RC7-Componentes!R5C12)))"

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
With ActiveSheet.Range("AN7")
    .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
    .Replace Parte1, theFormulaPart2
    .Replace Parte2, theFormulaPart3
End With
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
```

Hope somebody can help. I have done my research but at this point, breaking the code in several parts seems to solve the problem for everyone.

Comment: You cannot split the formula just like that. `theFormulaPart1` must _look_ like a real formula - matching brackets etc. So the trick is to replace whole inner nested formula - for example the big `INDEX(....)` in this case.

Comment: @BrakNicku is 100% right. The formula inside `theFormulaPart1` must be a working formula, not just text, to make the replace trick work. I've had in the past a similar issue. Check also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196290/error-1004-when-trying-to-use-formulaarray-replace-trick-does-not-work

Comment: You could use the name manager to split parts of your formula, this can/will make your formula below 255 characters

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. I think I am not understanding how to make 'theFormulaPart1' look like what's supposed to, because I tried different times and got the same error. I'm editing my post with my last try. @BrakNicku

Comment: Looks like you are getting close, but now you have 2 incorrect formulas in `theFormulaPart1`: INDEX and IF both with only 1 parameter. You should include those formulas in the replacement parts, so `theFormulaPart2 = "INDEX(....)"` and `theFormulaPart3 = "IF(....)"` and remove those parts from `theFormulaPart1`

Comment: @BrakNicku thank you again for your answer. I unsuccessfully tried with this:

`theFormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(IF([@[Estado 2]]=""Vigente"",IF(OR(RC15=Componentes!R16C2,RC15=Componentes!R17C2),RC17*(X_X_X())+VLOOKUP(RC23,Componentes!R58C5:R110C6,2,FALSE)*RC17*(Y_Y_Y()),""-""),""-""),""rev"")"`

Comment: What do you mean by _I unsuccessfully tried with this_? I am almost certain that this formula does not raise any errors. I hope you have already read the accepted answer to the question mentioned above by @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns explaining why you cannot mix A1 and R1C1 notations in this case and giving a simple workaround.

Comment: @BrakNicku I meant that I was getting the same error, but you were right. I misread the other question and didn't realise about the A1-R1C1 issue. I corrected the code (see update on the original post) but now is like the formula, after the replacements, is not valid. I sincerely appreciate your help with this, as I am really stucked here. Hope you can find what's the issue now.

Comment: But why did you decide to change some **unique** strings to be replaced (like `X_X_X`) with `1`? If you try to replace **all** occurences of `1` - it just cannot work right...

Comment: @BrakNicku I tried to do it as in the solution to the other question, so changed `X_X_X` and `Y_Y_Y` by `Parte1` and `Parte2` and defined them as `C1600` and 'C1601' as it was said in that question. It didn't work and then in this last versión I tried with 1 and 2...
Is it not necessary to use `Parte1` and `Parte2`? After that I didn't get the 1004 error in `.FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1`, that's why I thought I was in the correct way

Comment: Now I am completely lost, and have no idea what `C1600` is coming from. It doesn't really matter how you define `Parte1` but it has got to be unique string, try `Parte1 = "X_X_X"`,`Parte2 = "Y_Y_Y"`

Comment: Sorry I'll explain better: in the other question it's said that _the formulas need to be something that can be pasted without an error returning_ (as you also said), so a user recommends to set `Parte 1 = C16000` as a temporary value which will be replaced by the ´FormulaPart2´. I don't know why using `X_X_X()` wasn't working for me, but now I tried again applying to this case `Part1 = "C160"` and `Part2 = "C161"` and it worked. I remembered that when I tried it before, I had an error with one parenthesis missing in `theFormulaPart1` and `theFormulaPart2`, so it didn't work. @BrakNicku

Comment: Well as you can see I'm starting to code and I screw up a lot. You have helped me with several mistakes through this question. Thanks a lot @BrakNicku and the rest of users who answered!

Comment: Using "C160" might have worked, but it is very risky. `C160` can be a part R1C1 notation cell address, that is why maybe someone else suggested using `C16000` (not likely to see reference to 16000th column in a valid formula). I still do not understand why not "X_X_X".

Comment: @BrakNicku you're right. That method is less risky and the code worked fine (I think that's beacuse between my previous try and this last one, I corrected some errors like the parenthesis in the formulas). Thank you again!